# Ignore small changes in tensorflow scan

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to compare the current and previous values in scan, and modify current so that changes with respect to previous that are smaller than a threshold are ignored.  Also, how to count the number elements with a change greater than threshold?

Here's my attempt

```
def f(prev_y, curr_y):
    thrshd= 0.05
    diff = curr_y - prev_y
    pos_dif = tf.nn.relu(diff-thrshd)
    neg_dif = tf.nn.relu(-diff+thrshd)
    fval = prev_y + pos_dif - neg_dif
    return fval

a = tf.constant([[.1, .26, .3, .2, .15],
                 [.07, .35, .24, .23, .19]])

init = tf.constant([0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2])
c = tf.scan(f, a, initializer=init)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(c))
```

output:

```
[[0.05       0.21       0.25       0.15       0.10000001]
 [0.02       0.3        0.19       0.18       0.14      ]]
```

desired output:

```
[[0.1        0.26       0.30       0.20       0.2]
 [0.1        0.35       0.24       0.20       0.2  ]]
```

Number of changes above threshold: 3, 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where):

```
import tensorflow as tf

def f(prev_y, curr_y):
    thrshd= 0.05
    return tf.where(tf.greater(tf.abs(curr_y - prev_y), thrshd),
                    curr_y,
                    prev_y)

a = tf.constant([[.1, .26, .3, .2, .15],
                 [.07, .35, .24, .23, .19]])

init = tf.constant([0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2])
c = tf.scan(f, a, initializer=init)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(c)
```

)

Prints:

```
[[0.1  0.26 0.3  0.2  0.2 ]
 [0.1  0.35 0.24 0.2  0.2 ]]
```

To also count values above the threshold:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def f(accumulator, curr_y):
    prev_y, _ = accumulator
    thrshd= 0.05
    greater = tf.greater(tf.abs(curr_y - prev_y), thrshd)
    new_array = tf.where(greater, curr_y, prev_y)
    return (new_array, tf.count_nonzero(greater))

a = tf.constant([[.1, .26, .3, .2, .15],
                 [.07, .35, .24, .23, .19]])

init = tf.constant([0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2])
output_array, output_count  = tf.scan(
    f, a, initializer=(init, tf.zeros([], dtype=tf.int64)))
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run((output_array, output_count)))
```

Prints:

```
(array([[0.1 , 0.26, 0.3 , 0.2 , 0.2 ],
       [0.1 , 0.35, 0.24, 0.2 , 0.2 ]], dtype=float32), array([3, 2]))
```

Meaning 3 values were above threshold the first iterations, and 2 the second.